# How can I make the verticle line in the table without any gaps?

Tags: latex, tabular, overleaf

The verticle line in the third column has 2 gaps. How do I do I make it look full?

[image: 1]

Here's the code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Enzymatic cocktails and the respective tested concentrations in \%(v/v) used in Combined Hydrolysis}
\label{enzymatic cocktails}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Cocktail}  & \textbf{Enzymes}               & \textbf{Concentration \%(v/v)}                                              \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cellulase} & \multirow{8}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.25\\ 0.50\\ 1.00\end{tabular}} \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\boldsymbol{\beta}$-glucosidase}            &  \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
\multirow{3}{*}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cellulase}                &  \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\boldsymbol{\beta}$-glucosidase}            &  \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{xylanase}                 & \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
\multirow{3}{*}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cellulase}                &  \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\boldsymbol{\beta}$-glucosidase}            &  \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\boldsymbol{\beta}$-glucanase and xylanase} &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]. The gapes are created by the booktabs package.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical lines like in `c|` and horizontal lines such as `toprule`, `bottomrule`, `midrule`, `cmidrule` from the package [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) do not match.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[H]
\centering
\caption{Enzymatic cocktails and the respective tested concentrations in \%(v/v) used in Combined Hydrolysis}
\label{enzymatic_cocktails}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\hline
\textbf{Cocktail}  & \textbf{Enzymes}               & \textbf{Concentration \%(v/v)}\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cellulase} & %
  \multirow{8}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.25\\ 0.50\\ 1.00\end{tabular}}\\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mathbb{\beta}$-glucosidase}     & \\
                   \cline{1-2}
\multirow{3}{*}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cellulase}                        & \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\boldsymbol{\beta}$-glucosidase} & \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{xylanase}                         & \\
                   \cline{1-2}
\multirow{3}{*}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cellulase}                        & \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mathbb{\beta}$-glucosidase}     & \\
                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mathbb{\beta}$-glucanase and xylanase} & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

So I went back to `hline`s in my code. Better would be to use the above mentioned package [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and avoid vertical lines instead.